# COVID-19 Shock: Time Series not Stationary Anymore

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, structural-change, covid-19

I am trying to forecast the private consumption for 2020 of a small region based on the national time series of the same variable. With some adjustments I managed to get both the series stationary by taking the natural log and double differentiated  the time series. Then I estimated an ARIMA model which worked fine until 2019. However, the value for 2020, already available on national level destroyed everything: due to the COVID-19 shock the national time series isn't by far stationary anymore. Do you have any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Double integrating? Did you take the cumulative sum of the original series $x_t$ to obtain $y_t$ and then the cumulative sum of $y_t$ to obtain $z_t$ so that $\Delta^2 z_t=x_t$?

Comment: @RichardHardy sorry, I meant "double differenciated" the series, they originally were both I(2). The national statistics bureau releases trimestral data of the national time series, so that now I have the results of 2020 (which breaks stationarity). The regional time series is yearly and the result of 2020 will be released next year. Therefore I wanted to forecast 2020 at regional level given that there is a good correlation with the national series when both are stationary. However the data point at national level for 2020 destroyed the stationarity assumption.

Comment: If you could post some data that looks a bit like yours (before log and diff), it's easier to reply with a solution that solves your problem. There is a good selection of change point packages in R that may be appropriate, e.g., by doing ARIMA residuals on top of trends and using a log-link.